# Parsing out specific URLs from local html file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, hyperlink, parsing

I want to parse out certain URLs from a saved **html**-file with a simple bash-script/command, so i can download them via `wget` laters.
 
What i have so far is:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS="<a *href *= *\""} NR>2 {sub(/".*/,"");print; }' index.html >> url-list.txt
```

which writes every link that is inside my html-file into a neat txt-document.

What i need, however, are only specific links

- from a certain domain
- all .ogg files for example

everything that in the end would look like:

http://www.foo.com/(randomfolder)/(randombasename).ogg

or

http://subdomain.foo.com/(randomfolder)/(anotherrandomsubfolder)/(randombasename).ogg

thanks in advance!

Comment: Need to do this with pure Bash/sed/awk or are scripting languages fine too?

Comment: would need it with bash so i can merge it easily with other scripts i wrote, thanks. I'm pretty new to this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say you need to do it "in Bash", but you seem to mean "in a script" and not "using pure Bash syntax" (there is a difference). I assume you want the "in a script" meaning.

---

If you have saved all the links on separate lines in a document, you can pick out all links on the domain `http://www.example.com/` with e.g.

```
grep "^http://www\.example\.com/" filewithlinks.txt
```

or all links ending with `.ogg` with

```
grep "\.ogg$" filewithlinks.txt
```

(The backslash preceding periods is to escape the "`.`" sign which otherwise means "any character". "`\.`" instead mean a literal period. Without escaping you'll match links ending with e.g. "logg" as well.)

You could also do line matching directly in the `awk`  command, but that would be more complicated to change from time to time, I believe. The easiest way is to save the complete list of links in a file as you do and then just search the file with  for example `grep` as above. Then you also won't have to download and parse the document again if you want to change matching pattern.

Comment: yes, thanks, i mean, doing it with a simple bash script, using awk, sed, or something else (as implied by the tags). ----- I tried your suggestion on my saved html-page, but it didn't work. My script above parses (reads out) every URL that it finds inside the `a href` tags of the html file and copies them to a plain txt file, line by line. You might want to try our scripts to see what i mean. For example, save this page, then only keep the links that follow http://meta.superuser.com/ or http://superuser.com/users/ for a start...

Comment: @Kai: I tried it on a saved HTML page. Your `awk` script rendered a file with one link per line, which is what I called `filewithlinks.txt` above. Using `grep` as above on this file as I wrote (nb: not `index.html`) worked as I described, and should for you as well. Look up some simple `grep` examples if this tool is new for you (it is very simple: it prints all lines that match the given expression. "`^`" means beginning of line, "`$`" means end of line).

Comment: oic, thanks, I'm sorry, overread that. I have to combine the two then. I tried `grep "^http://*superuser\.com/" filewithlinksfromsuperuser.txt >> allsuperuserlinks.txt` but it only got me the superuser.com links, when i wanted the **subdomains** blog.superuser.com and meta.superuser.com too... **How do i use the asterisk** right? (insisting because it was part of my question, sorry :) Any way to grep links that have a certain amount of numbers in it, like www.foo.com/12345 and www.foo.com/subfolder/123456. Or should i open a new question?

Comment: @Kai: This is all in the functionality of `grep` (in this specific case: use `.*`, since "`.`" means "any character", and "`*`" means "the previous character zero or more times"). You should read up on regular expressions for more advanced cases, but the sky is the limit (even more so when using `grep -E`), which makes it hold too much information to cram into a comment field :-) .

Comment: okay, thanks for this solution. --- the grep i am looking for would have been `grep "^http://.*superuser\.com/" filewithlinksfromsuperuser.txt >> su-subdomainlinks.txt` and `grep "^http://superuser\.com/\users/[0-9]\{3,6\}" filewithlinksfromsuperuser.txt >> all su-users-links.txt`